# How to count the number of sheets in a workbook using a loop in VBA?

Tags: vba

I want to count the number of sheets in a workbook without using the count formula, but to use a loop to find it. Kindly help.

Comment: `NumofSheets = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count` , not good for you ?

Comment: No, because this sounds like a homework problem.

Comment: @ Shai Rado, I am trying to get the count without using count.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub CountSheets()
  Dim nCount As Integer
  Dim s As Worksheet

  For Each s In Sheets
    nCount = nCount + 1
  Next

  MsgBox nCount
End Sub
```